# CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn hook works on local but not when built in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy

With reference to [this article by SamStephens](http://blog.samstephens.co.nz/2010-10-18/msbuild-including-extra-files-multiple-builds/) and [this by Sayed](http://sedodream.com/2013/09/21/HowToExtendTheWebPublishProcessWithoutModifyingProjectContents.aspx), I have managed to include additional dependent files during packaging ***when built LOCALLY*** using Visual Studio 2012.

The issue starts when I built the codes in TFS. Looking through the logs, it looks like the CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn is not hooked on.

```
CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn = 
     ;
     ;

CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn = 
     ;
     ;
```

So I have a Deployment.csproj with a CreatePackage.targets file and in this target file, it would build the web application project. The following is the snippet of the file which I combine what I learned from both the articles stated earlier.

```
  <!-- Create Web Deploy package for local build. -->
  <Target Name="WebPackage" Condition="'$(TfsBuild)' == ''">
    <!-- MSBuild the project. -->
    <MSBuild Projects="..\webapplication.csproj"
             Targets="Package" 
             Properties="
             Platform=$(Platform);
             VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
             Configuration=$(Configuration);
             WebPublishMethod=Package;
             ExcludeApp_Data=false;
             DeployOnBuild=true;
             DeployTarget=Package;
             PackageAsSingleFile=true;
             PackageLocation=$(PackageOutputDirectory);
             PublishProfile=$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath);
             ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment=Scripts;             
             ExcludeFilesFromDeployment=parameters.xml;">            
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>  

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      DefineAssemblies;
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>

    <AssemblySource Condition="'$(TfsBuild)' == ''">$(SolutionDir)\ProjectA\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectA.dll</AssemblySource>        

    <AssemblySource Condition="'$(TfsBuild)' == 'true'">$(OutputDirectory)ProjectA.dll</AssemblySource>

  <Target Name="DefineAssemblies">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToInclude Include="$(AssemblySource)">
        <Dir>lib</Dir>
      </FilesToInclude >
    </ItemGroup>    
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">    
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(FilesToInclude )">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(FilesToInclude.Dir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

So the question is: Why is this working nicely locally in VS2012 and not in the TFS build?
I've been stuck in this for two days now so I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried the /pp switch on msbuild command? When property **CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn** ocur? Can you see any difference between resulted msbuild project file on your local machine and on the build server?

Comment: Interesting question: have you tried raising the MSBuild logging level?